# parse multiple options into route condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have an instance where I would like multiple variations to resolve to one view. Is there a way of doing this without repeating the function within routes?

Example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tools'], function () {
    Route::any('', function () {
        return View::make("tools.profile");
    });
    Route::any('/', function () {
        return View::make("tools.profile");
    });
    Route::any('view', function () {
        return View::make("tools.profile");
    });
    Route::any('view/{id}', 'Tools@profileUpdate', function ($id) {});
});
```

In the above example I would like `''`, `/` and `view` to resolve to view `View::make("tools.profile")`.

Is there something like below an option, where an array can be parsed?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tools'], function () {
    Route::any(['','/','view'], function () {
        return View::make("tools.profile");
    });
    Route::any('view/{id}', 'Tools@profileUpdate', function ($id) {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tools'], function () {
    Route::get('/{name}',function(){
        return View::make("tools.profile");
    })->where('name', '|/|view');
    Route::any('view/{id}', 'Tools@profileUpdate', function ($id) {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes u can do by array

```
$routes = array('','/','view');
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    Route::get($route, function () {
        return view('tools.profile');
    });
}
```

if you want pass `route(viewname)` then do like this by using `closures`

```
$routes = array('','/','view');
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    Route::get($route, function () use ($route) {
        info("view name ".$route);
        return view('tools.profile');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must simply invest what you are doing:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tools'], function () {
    Route::get('view/{id}', 'Tools@profileUpdate');
    Route::get('{x}', function ($x) {
        return view("tools.profile");
    });
});
```

And if you want more security:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tools'], function () {
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Tools@profileUpdate');
        Route::get('{x}', function ($x) {
            if($x == '' || $x == '/' || $x == 'view'){
            return view("tools.profile");
            }else{
               /*Redirect to some where or make a error view or someting*/
            }
        });
    });
```